# How to pass data from Fragment to Tablayout fragment

Tags: java, android-studio

This is will run fragment in fragment that use viewpageAdapter.I want to pass data from fragment to tablayout fragment. i have try any method and still crash. i just want to passs once data to fragment in the tablayout.

First fragment.  this line i want pass to tablayout fragment:-

`specItem = getArguments().getString("spec_item");`

```
@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    imageUrl = getArguments().getString("image_url");
    priceItem = getArguments().getString("price_item");
    specItem = getArguments().getString("spec_item");

}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_view_details_item, container, false);

    textPrice = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.textPrice);
    image_Details = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.image_Detail);
    tabLayout = (TabLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tablayout_id);
    viewPager = (ViewPager) rootView.findViewById(R.id.viewpage_id);

    textPrice.setText(priceItem);

    Picasso.get().load(imageUrl).into(image_Details);

    ViewPageAdapter adapter = new ViewPageAdapter(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager());
    adapter.AddFragment(new FragmentSpecifications(), "Specification");
    adapter.AddFragment(new FragmentReview(), "Review");

    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);


    return rootView;
}
```

Second fragment in tablayout, i dont know how to recieve:-

```
View rootView;

TextView textSpec;
String specItem;
public FragmentSpecifications() {
}
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_specification, container, false);

    textSpec = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.textviewspec);

    textSpec.setText();

    return rootView;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside your `FragmentSpecifications` create a instance of the `Fragment` to send data to it, like this:

```
public static FragmentSpecifications newInstance(String priceItem) {

    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString("priceItem", priceItem);
    FragmentSpecifications fragment = new FragmentSpecifications();
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}
```

After that in same `FragmentSpecifications` override `onCreate` method and get value:

```
private String priceItem;

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (getArguments() != null)
       priceItem = getArguments().getString("priceItem");
}
```

And finally when you add `FragmentSpecifications` do adapter pass the value:

```
adapter.AddFragment(FragmentSpecifications.newInstance(priceItem), "Specification");
```

Comment: this answer work properly but when i go back and i enter inside again the data will missing. Why and how to fix it?

Comment: just go back page and enter again the data will missing

Comment: I don't know the workflow of your app, you can always make a variable `static` to keep in lifetime of whole application but, keep in mind that you need to properly handle `static` variables or you will get some bugs in app.

Comment: can i show before and after? after 4 hours i tried to search any method , still same.

Comment: by the way that tablayout will empty text by the default. so the original text can't show why ?